# Android onEnabled/onDisabled never called

Tags: android, android-widget, action, appwidgetprovider

I'm having a problem with triggering of the onEnabled and onDisabled methods of the AppWidgetReciever. I have the actions specified, I also log every action in onRecieve method, but the only two actions I get are "APPWIDGET_UPDATE" and "APPWIDGET_DELETED". I have googled for this solution, but unfortunately found none. Here is my code:

Manifest part:

```
<receiver android:name=".ScheduleWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" /> 
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_xml" />
        </receiver>
```

Provider_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="180dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="60000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:configure="org.zivkovic.schedule.ConfigurationActivity"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

ScheduleWidgetProvider:

```
public class ScheduleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    {
        Log.w("Schedule", "ScheduleWidgetProviderRequested");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w("Schedule", "On recieve " + intent.getAction());
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        Log.w("Schedule", "OnEnabled called");
        ...
        super.onEnabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        Log.w("Schedule", "OnDisabled called");

        ...

        super.onDisabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            ....
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, removing my app from the phone did the trick. Can't understand why uninstall fixed it. With anyone having the same problem, uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this worked for me. My bet is, that widgets tie to the system deeper, and reinstall didn't affect the behavior. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It worked for me too, but why? I have this problem just **sometimes** when i install my App for test on the device by `AndroidStudio`. I also put all of require `intent-filter`s but i see this problem sometimes yet and it need `uninstall` + `reinstall` again.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but it seems that the problem is the `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method.

As it appears, it takes precedence in handling receiver's events, preventing `AppWidgetProvider`'s designated methods from being called upon receiving action.

There are two possible solutions; either handle intent's action in the `onReceive` method, or remove the method and override the designated action methods.

Do not forget to include the actions in the intent-filter.

Comment: In your onReceive, you need to call the super method first, in order to have the dispatch to onEnabled, onDisabled, etc.

Comment: @lukas Yes, Yes, Yes! Calling `super.OnReceive` did the trick!